# When I start a loop by pressing a button it loops once then freezes

Tags: vb.net

My program freezes after looping once.

I have tried replacing the conditions for the loop and made it just loop indefinitely but it always does the same thing.

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button3.Click

        ballX = Button2.Location.X + 1
        ballY = Button2.Location.Y + 1
        Dim g As Integer
        Dim h As Integer

        h = Button2.Location.X


        Do Until h > 856
            Button2.Location = New Point(ballX, ballY)
            Me.Update()
        Loop

    End Sub
```

It is supposed to move a button until it hits the side of the program and then stop. All it does is moves the button 1px then you can't interact with the program anymore. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Your code runs on the same thread that updates your UI. Your code is in an infinite loop so the UI never gets to update (despite the `Me.Update()`). You need to do your updates as part of a timer or use the `Async`/`Await` features.

Comment: I will try these things, thanks!

Comment: The reason this is an infinite loop is that you never update h inside the loop.

Comment: @CarrickMullin I think you might be under the impression that since you set `h=Button2.location.X`, the loop will check `Location.X` on every iteration. This is NOT the case, `h` doesn't change even though `Location.X` might. Inside the loop you will want to increment some value, and make sure it is possible for `h > 856` To be true at some point, otherwise it will loop forever. Note that since you dont change `ballX`and `ballY ` in the loop either, the only change that is ever actually done is on the first iteration of your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try

```
Do Until h > 856
    Button2.Location = New Point(ballX, ballY)

    ballX = Button2.Location.X + 1
    ballY = Button2.Location.Y + 1
    h = Button2.Location.X

    Me.Update() 
Loop
```